# Is there more pythonic way to compare two lists items with replacing the matched items but taking into account that there can be duplicates?

Tags: python, list, compare, list-comprehension

Below is a way I do now with correct output, because I do need not all same items to be replaced but only the occurences that are occured:

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y']
b = ['y', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'q', 'x']
c = []
exist = []
for index_a, value_a in enumerate(a):
    for b_index, value_b in enumerate(b):
        if value_a == value_b:
            b[b_index] = value_b.replace(value_b, 'b_matched-' + value_b)
            ind = index_a
            value_a = 'a_matched-' + value_a
            exist.append(ind)
            if ind not in exist:
                c.append(value_a)
    if value_a not in b:
        c.append(value_a)
a = c
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output (correct):

```
['a_matched-x', 'a_matched-y', 'a_matched-x', 'y']
['b_matched-y', 'b_matched-x', 'z', 'b_matched-x', 'x', 'q', 'x']
```

But I wnat it to be shorter like a list comprehension below but only with the output like above.

```
a1 = a
a = [x if x not in b else 'a_matched-'+ x for x in a]
b = [x if x not in a1 else 'b_matched-'+ x for x in b]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output: (incorrect because all maches of the item are replaced):

```
['a_matched-x', 'a_matched-y', 'a_matched-x', 'a_matched-y']
['b_matched-y', 'b_matched-x', 'z', 'b_matched-x', 'b_matched-x', 'q', 'b_matched-x']
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `collections.Counter` class can help. Its supported operators to allow (multi)set-like operations to easily create e.g. an intersection.

Comment: I do now how to leave only non-matched, it's not a n issue. But I need to know how to replace others in the shortest version (list comprehension is the best).